# Is There a way to create a form with nested elements in react with each element having a unique name?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react form, and I want to create groups and many sections under each group, where each section will have many items to fill under it. Something like this:

```
<Form>
  <FormGroup name="group1">
    <FormGroup name="section1">
      <FormItem name="item1">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem name="item2">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      ...
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup name="section2">
      <FormItem name="item1">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem name="item2">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      ...
    </FormGroup>
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup name="group2">
    <FormGroup name="section1">
      <FormItem name="item1">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem name="item2">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      ...
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup name="section2">
      <FormItem name="item1">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem name="item2">
        <Input name="name1" /> 
        ...
      </FormItem>
      ...
    </FormGroup>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

I want that when I submit the form, I should have the different values with not only their corresponding names but also the groups and sections to which they belong. I would like if possible, to get the values in a nested object format like:

```
group1: {
  section1: {
    item1: value1,
    item2: value2,
    ...
  },
  section2: {
    item1: value1,
    item2: value2,
    ...
  },
},
group2: {
  section1: {
    item1: value1,
    item2: value2,
    ...
  },
  section2: {
    item1: value1,
    item2: value2,
    ...
  },
},

Thank you in advance.
```

I tries using antd with their Form.Item component in a nested way but when I submit the form all I get is the values with their specific input element name not the outer element's name. React-advanced-from package has something similar that can work but I could get it installed, I think it might be broken.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this would be to use a combination of the state and event handlers in React to store and retrieve the values of the form fields. In your Form component, you can use the useState hook to create state variables for each group, section, and item. You can then use the onChange event handler on each input element to update the corresponding state variable when the user enters a value.

For example, in your Form component, you can create a state variable for each group like this:

```
const [group1, setGroup1] = useState({});
const [group2, setGroup2] = useState({});
```

Then, in each FormGroup component, you can create state variables for each section:

```
const [section1, setSection1] = useState({});
const [section2, setSection2] = useState({});
```

Finally, in each FormItem component, you can create a state variable for each item:

```
const [item1, setItem1] = useState('');
const [item2, setItem2] = useState('');
```

You can then use the onChange event handler on each input element to update the corresponding state variable:

```
<Input name="name1" value={item1} onChange={(e) => setItem1(e.target.value)} />
```

When the form is submitted, you can use the setGroup1, setGroup2, setSection1, setSection2, setItem1, and setItem2 functions to update the state and retrieve the values in the format you specified:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
        group1: {
            section1: {
                item1: item1,
                item2: item2,
                ...
            },
            section2: {
                item1: item1,
                item2: item2,
                ...
            },
        },
        group2: {
            section1: {
                item1: item1,
                item2: item2,
                ...
            },
            section2: {
                item1: item1,
                item2: item2,
                ...
            },
        },
    };
    console.log(formData);
};
```

Please let me know if you face any problems.